# Email validation is not working when using on data annotation on my View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, data-annotations

I have an email that created for both model and view, what could be an issue exactly? When i inspect this i dont see any error from the browser, below is my logic for this validation that i am doing on the form using asp.net mvc.

```
                        <div class="row">
                        <label for"Email">Email:</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", id = "inputEmail" , placeholder = "example@example.com", 
                                required = "required",
                                 pattern = @"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$", title = "This field is required"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, " ", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        // Model
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing `Pattern` and `Required` in the view? Shouldn't the DataAnnotations do those? Try:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[RegularExpression("^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\z", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
```

You might want to use another regular expression.

And then in the View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

Comment: Rahatur do these expression are accepted by.net framework, getting some error to it? "Unrecognized space expression"

Comment: Im still not winning here Rahatur

Comment: @metro2020Flavor Yes, .net framework code. Should work. Try to add a '@' character in the regular expression like `[RegularExpression(@"^[\w...`